# VBA: Excel Macro executes correctly in debug, but does not run sub when executed

Tags: vba, excel

My code is to reference a named range(Pump Number), find the last instance in a table(another sheet), copy the row it was found in and paste that data in the new row that was created in the table. It is then to loop trough a series of cells on another sheet and find true values. If the value is true it is to copy another named range(Hours) and paste that value into the table in the correct column. The code executes correctly in debug, stepping through one line at a time, but when ran  normally, it does not copy the last line of data in the table and paste the values in the new row. The code where it does not work properly starts at line 90

```
Sub SavePumpMaintenance()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim tbla As ListObject, last_row, total_stage As Integer
    Dim issue, pump, pump_hrs, main_date, main_code As String
    Dim correct_plunger, correct_part As Boolean, Data As Worksheet
    Dim Maint As Worksheet, wSheet As Worksheet, r As Long
    Dim tbl As ListObject, newrow As ListRow, i As Long
    Dim cells As Range, LR As Integer, Hist As Worksheet

    Set Hist = Sheet26
    Set CurrentHours = Range("CurrentHours")
    Set tbl = Hist.ListObjects("Historical")
    Set newrow = tbl.ListRows.Add
    Set Data = Sheet5
    Set Maint = Sheet3
    Set tbla = Maint.ListObjects("MaintPerformed")
    correct_plunger = Data.Range("N6").Value
    correct_part = Data.Range("N10").Value
    main_code = Data.Range("Y8").Value
    issue = Data.Range("Y11").Value
    last_row = Data.Range("N11").Value
    pump = Maint.Range("C6").Value
    pump_hrs = Maint.Range("C7").Value
    main_date = Maint.Range("C8").Value
    total_stage = Maint.Range("C9").Value
    LR = tbl.Range(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'Unprotect all sheets
    For Each wSheet In Worksheets
        wSheet.Unprotect Password:="SomePassword"
    Next wSheet
    If pump = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please select a pump."
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If pump_hrs = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter hours."
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Range("Date") = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter date and time of maintenance."
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If correct_plunger = False Then
        MsgBox "Incorrect plunger type selected"
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If correct_part = False Then
        MsgBox "Incorrect part type selected"
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Data.Range("T3:T37").Copy 'Copy used parts/pump info to maintenance table
    Maint.Range("O1").Offset(last_row,0).PasteSpecial xlValues,Transpose:=True
    Data.Range("U3:U12").Copy
    Maint.Range("BJ1").Offset(last_row,0).PasteSpecial xlValues,Transpose:=True
    Maint.Range("J1").Offset(last_row, 0).Value = pump
    Maint.Range("J1").Offset(last_row, 1).Value = pump_hrs
    Maint.Range("J1").Offset(last_row, 2).Value = total_stage
    Maint.Range("J1").Offset(last_row, 3).Value = main_date
    Maint.Range("J1").Offset(last_row, 4).Value = main_code
    Maint.Range("J1").Offset(last_row, 63).Value = issue

    'Copy last set of historical data for pump 'add maintenance to history
    For r = 1 To LR Step 1
        If tbl.Range(r, 1).Value = Range("Pumpnumber") Then
            Range("H" & r & ":V" & r).Copy
            newrow.Range(8).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
        End If
    Next r
    With newrow 'Paste current pump information
        .Range(1) = Range("Pumpnumber")
        .Range(2) = Range("Date")
        .Range(3) = CurrentHours
        .Range(4) = Range("Position")
        .Range(5) = Range("Fleet")
        .Range(6) = Range("WFNumb")
        .Range(7) = Range("OStage")
    End With

    'copy hours from maintenance if checked into maint. history
    For i = 1 To 5
        If Maint.cells(13, i + 2).Value = True Then
            CurrentHours.Copy
            newrow.Range(7 + i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
        If Maint.cells(16, i + 2).Value = True Then
            CurrentHours.Copy
            newrow.Range(12 + i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
        If Maint.cells(21, i + 2).Value = True Then
            CurrentHours.Copy
            newrow.Range(17 + i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
        If Maint.cells(22, i + 2).Value = True Then
            CurrentHours.Copy
            newrow.Range(17 + i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next i
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Dim mp As Range, P As Range 'Copy Current hrs to Equipment Sheet
    Set mp = Range("MyPumps")
    For Each P In mp
        If P.Value = Range("PumpNumber") Then
            P.Offset(0, 5).Value = Range("CurrentHours")
        End If
    Next P

    Sheet3.Protect Password:="MyPassword"  'Protect sheets
    Sheet5.Protect Password:="MyPassword"
    Sheet16.Protect Password:="MyPassword"
    Sheet25.Protect Password:="MyPassword"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: Put a breakline on the last line (that isn't working), run the code until it stops itself, and then check the values of related variables.  My *guess* would be that you're not explicitly referring to the correct destination sheet, which you're manually choosing it when running the code line by line.  Also I'm going to edit your post to remove irrelevant stuff like commented-out code. Check out the [tour] (you'll earn your first badge!) and also see "[ask]" as well as how to create an [mcve].

Comment: If you add the line `Option Explicit` to the top of the module, it will help "force" you to properly declare/handle your variables.  Also, note that you posted your password. I changed it but it's still permanently viewable in the history. If it's of concern then you can flag a mod to help.

Comment: I think what the problem is, it is not copying even when true.

Comment: `Set CurrentHours = Range("CurrentHours")` looks suspect because it's implicitly referencing the `ActiveSheet`. Try qualifying your call to `Range`.

Comment: Failing to copy when running at full speed, but working fine when 'stepping' *might* suggest that the code is moving on to the next line before the last copy or paste has completed..? To rule this out, add a `DoEvents` line after **every** `Copy` and `Paste` within the loop that's failing. This will cause Excel to pause until any events, such as recalcs and large copy/pastes have completed before continuing.

Comment: Found the error. Thank you everyone for your help. Turns out there was a reference error. Once i got rid of all the "activates" and added the reference to everything it works flawlessly.